# JQuery removeClass not working on self

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a class called:

> `<div class="upvote"></div>`

I'm currently using jquery to try to upvote something and animate the disappearance. I do not want one person to be able to upvote the same thing multiple times without refreshing the page.

If I use

> `$(".upvote").click(function(){
>       $(this).fadeOut(); 
>       $.ajax({...});
>   }`

It alters the code and changes the layout. So I am using

> `$(".upvote").click(function(){
>       $(this).animate({opacity: "0.0"}); 
>       $.ajax({...});
>   }`

This does not change the layout of the page; however, it allows the person to vote multiple times without refreshing the page. I am tryin

> `$(".upvote").click(function(){
>       $(this).animate({opacity: "0.0"}); 
>       $(this).removeClass("upvote");
>       $.ajax({...});
>   }`

so that it won't trigger the JQuery anymore, but it isn't working. What should I do?

I've looked few through a few other Stack Overflow threads but could not seem to find the answer.

Comment: I think the event is still binding with the element although you remove the class on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this.

You can use event delegation and remove the class.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.upvote', function () {
    $(this).animate({ opacicty: 0.0 }).removeClass('upvote');
});
```

You can also use `one` which will remove the handler automatically once invoked.

```
$(".upvote").one('click', function() { ... });
```

However, it's hard to understand why they should be allowed to vote again once they reload the page? There's no real difference between being allowed to vote multiple times without refreshing vs when refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is .one();

**.one()**

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Using .one() will ensure your event will only run once per event per element.

Basic Usage:

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

---

**.on()**

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Generally speaking, You should use .on to attach event handlers using jQuery.

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert("clicked")
});
```

---

**.off()**

http://api.jquery.com/off/

You can use .off() to remove any event handlers that were attached previously using .on().

```
$( "#foo" ).off();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and most important thing is:

This is only the client side of the code where you are trying to prevent the user from submitting multiple votes. Pay attention as anyone could use the developer tools in their browsers to send the ajax request again and again.

So I would rather prevent the voting in the model and the database structure behind the scenes before fixing a simple UI issue.

The second thing is:

If your page is being refreshed after clicking the button, I reckon you need to change the "type" attribute of your button from "submit" to "button". The first and the second code should be fine to get the result you want.

Look at the code @plalx put in the answers for a better one.

Hope this helps!